# How to extract certain keyframe from current scene to another file with just the selected keyframe as first and only keyframe?

Tags: animation

I have a animation of several objects falling one after another. My baked sequence last up to ~13500 frames. It is a simulation of the constructive process of a breakwater.

I want to extract my final result of the baked animation, this is, the last keyframe of my scene as a single scene on another .blend file. In which my last keyframe is the first keyframe of the new file.

I don't know which is the proper approach to achieve this, I've been looking out and trying diffent things (delete all keyframes and save as new file, append scene from target file...) but I can't achieve exactly what I want.

I hope you can help me,

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BEFORE you try my solution, make a backup!

1. go to your last frame, select all objects
2. in the timeline press "I", select "all channels"

> This creates a keyframe for every object+property which already has keyframes so that we later can move this keyframe to the start

[image]

3. now select just the last keyframe

[image]

4. press CTRL-I to invert selection

> Now all keyframes for all objects except for the last frame should be selected

5. press X -> delete keyframes

> Now you should only keyframes on your last frame

6. select all keyframes again
7. move them to your first frame
8. save this file under a new name

Ready

Comment: Thanks for your submission, I think I have an issue I didn't point out. As I ended and saved, all keyframes still on cache and animation replays, Is there any way to delete current state apart from cache saved? But If I delete all cache memory, what I obtain is the starting situation, where objects are ready and waiting to fall at its target keyframe.

Comment: you can just hit "delete bake" in scene properties -> rigid body world -> cache. But of course, if an object has rigid body - you cannot expect that there is no animation if you clear your cache. Of course it will fall down. If you don't want that, you have to delete the rigid body from the objects.